# Python (requests) encoding trouble (UTF-8 - CP1251)

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-requests, cp1251

I trying to get this kind of URL `http://example.com/?param=%DD%CC%C0-15` with `requests` python extension like this:

```
group = "ЭМА-15".encode('cp1251')
r = requests.get('http://example.com/?param=' + group)
r.encoding = "cp1251"
```

(because site works with windows-1251 (cp1251) encoding)

And getting errorat line 2: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 82: invalid continuation byte`
But this sequence of bytes (0xDD (%DD)...) is exactly what I need.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Please have a look my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things.
1. Python interpreter needs to know the encoding of "ЭМА-15" string in the source
2. query parameter is usually handled by `requests` but since you are constructing the URL manually, it's best to quote it by yourself.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
import requests

group = u"ЭМА-15".encode('cp1251')
param = urllib.quote_plus(group)
print(param)
r = requests.get('http://example.com/?param=' + param)
```

Output

```
%DD%CC%C0-15
```

Comment: I was waiting for a such answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to display `cp1251` characters but your editor is configured to use `utf8`
The `coding: cp1251` is only used by the Python interpreter to convert characters from source python files that are outside of the ASCII range. Try:

```
group = "ЭМА-15".decode('utf8').encode('cp1251')
r = requests.get('http://example.com/?param=' + group)
r.encoding = "cp1251"
```

When I run on my terminal,

```
>>> "ЭМА-15".decode('utf8').encode('cp1251')
'\xdd\xcc\xc0-15'
```

Comment: No, it prints successfully, the problem is in the request function